# How to cross field validate only fields that match my custom constraint?

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

Assume this bean:

```java
@OneOf(field1 = "fieldA", field2 = "fieldB")
public class bean{

@Size( min = 2, max = 40)
private String fieldA; // "I'm the content"

@Size( min = 1, max = 15)
private String fieldB; // ""


// getter & setter
}
```

The annotation @OneOf will validate, that one of the two is not null and not empty.
In my case I will fail on validating the size of fieldB.

Shoud I add in OneOf constaint, the size of my fields, and remove the @size ?

Comment: You can remove `min` validation for `fieldB` I think it's useless

Comment: I also would like to validate the min size of my string, when one of them isn't empty